# Force decimals in html inputs with InputMask html (jqueryl or js)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I want to force my html input the following display: 14 mantissa maximun(from 1 to 14) and the Effective Three decimal point, if the user does not specify the value of the points after they take the default 000
Example: Enter 5  show   5.000
enter 5.2 Show 5.200
enter 22222 show 22222.000 display.
please help

Comment: Please show some effort. What have you tried?

Comment: belive I made a lot of effort from yesterdays that I could get this solution to my problem because it is more complex than that , but a solution like this can be enough, I look everywhere but I did not find an answer .

Comment: how if the value 12-14 digit? became "123456789123.000"(became 15 digit long)?

Comment: @najeh22 I'm not even questioning that you have made an effort. I'm just asking you to show us your failed attempts, so we have something to improve on.

Comment: in my data base table i have price numeric(16,3)

Comment: I tried first jquery inputmasque with the plugin digital bash , the problem is whith the optionanal value , i can't add  decimal 000 if I put only digital value, after that i passed to regex and i start creating my own expression but it doesn't work: like this var ex=/[0-9]{1-14}(\.[0-9]{3} |(\.000)$/;

Comment: I tried this but I still have problemes with it ,checkDec(el){ var ex=/^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{2}$/; if(ex.test(el.value)==false){ el.value = el.value.substring(0,el.value.length - 1); } } ,I use onkeyup in html.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.indexOf` to check for the `.` character. Make sure it's there and check the length of the `substring` that goes after its index. If it's less then 3, add some zeros.

### HTML

```
<input type="text" id="input" maxlength="14" value="" />
```

### JavaScript

```
/* Select the desired input, and add an onChange event listener */
document.querySelector('#input').onchange = function () {
    /* if the user didn't add a dot, we add one with 3 zeros */
    if (this.value.indexOf('.') == -1) this.value += '.000';

    /* Otherwise, we check how many numbers there are after the dot
       and make sure there's at least 3*/
    if (this.value.substring(this.value.indexOf('.') + 1).length < 3)
        while (this.value.substring(this.value.indexOf('.') + 1).length < 3)
            this.value += '0';
};
```

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/4CHfC/)

Comment: thank you, it 's fine, but i still have probleme with regular expression

Comment: @najeh22 There are no regular expressions in my answer, so I don't know what your problem is. Also: [**How to accept an answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/191759).

Comment: your answer answers part of the question, but because of the other party which is not yet solved, my problem is not solved.
I need a regex expression to force the display of the real part, I tested the input mask with your solution, but it gives no good result.

Comment: What do you mean by "force the display of the real part" ? I don't see that part in your original question.

Comment: I want to force my html input the following display: 14 digital maximun(from 1 to 14) and  Three decimal point.from 0.000 to 99999999999999.999

Comment: 14 numbers maximum before the point.

Comment: I find the solution http://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/fhYAs/

Answer (score 1):

1. check if the number match `(\d{1,14})(\.\d{1,3}){0,1}`
2. split by .(dot) char
3. check the length of the second array result
4. add .000 if null or ajust if have 1 or 2 length by add 2 or 1 zero

Comment: I tried this but I still have problemes with it ,checkDec(el){ var ex=/^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{2}$/; if(ex.test(el.value)==false){ el.value = el.value.substring(0,el.value.length - 1); } } ,I use onkeyup in html.

Comment: [see this](http://jsfiddle.net/4BcF5/). i think that will be clear enough for you to get what you need. and i said `split(".")` not `substring()`